# Solr SnowballPorterFilterFactory filter provides incorrect sugestions

Tags: solr, spell-checking, search-suggestion, snowballanalyzer

I use SnowballPorterFilterFactory for index and query analyzers.
Search for "apple" word.
Solr successfully finds necessary articles, but tels that the word was spelled incorrect and give suggestion: "appl".
It works correct if I search for "apples": no suggestion is given and found articles with "apple" word.

schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_en.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords_en.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any ideas how to exclude incorrect suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the same field for search & spellchecking... Add a field without stemming for spellchecking.

**Example :**

```
<!-- Basic Text Field for use with Spell Correction -->
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<!-- TextSpell -->
<field name="textSpelling" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Then in your solrconfig.xml :

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">textSpelling</str>
      <str name="termSourceField">textSpelling</str>
      <str name="accuracy">0.7</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
      <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text</str>
      <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```